# NodeJS - convert relative path to absolute

Tags: javascript, node.js, relative-path, absolute-path

In my *File-system* my working directory is here:

**C:\temp\a\b\c\d**

and under b\bb there's file: tmp.txt

**C:\temp\a\b\bb\tmp.txt**

If I want to go to this file from my working directory, I'll use this path:

```
"../../bb/tmp.txt"
```

In case the file is not exist I want to log the full path and tell the user:
**"The file C:\temp\a\b\bb\tmp.txt is not exist"**.

**My question:**

I need some **function** that *convert* the relative path: "../../bb/tmp.txt" to absolute: "C:\temp\a\b\bb\tmp.txt"

In my code it should be like this:

```
console.log("The file" + convertToAbs("../../bb/tmp.txt") + " is not exist")
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_path)

try:

```
resolve = require('path').resolve
resolve('../../bb/tmp.txt')
```

Comment: you can also use `const {resolve} = require("path");`

Comment: @DarkKnight, Is there any way to avoid ../../../etc?

Comment: @Code_Crash you can use a variable or change working directory like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19803748/4578017 A variable is preferred since changing working directory might cause unwanted side effects

Comment: with the newer `esm` it is `import path from 'path'` and then `path.resolve()`.

Answer (score 14):

You could also use `__dirname and __filename` for absolute path.

Comment: Use this only to know the absolute path of the current directory in which the file resides and the current file respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**If you can't use require:**

```js
const path = {
    /**
    * @method resolveRelativeFromAbsolute resolves a relative path from an absolute path
    * @param {String} relitivePath relative path
    * @param {String} absolutePath absolute path
    * @param {String} split default?= '/', the path of the filePath to be split wth 
    * @param {RegExp} replace default?= /[\/|\\]/g, the regex or string to replace the filePath's splits with 
    * @returns {String} resolved absolutePath 
    */
    resolveRelativeFromAbsolute(relitivePath, absolutePath, split = '/', replace = /[\/|\\]/g) {
        relitivePath = relitivePath.replaceAll(replace, split).split(split);
        absolutePath = absolutePath.replaceAll(replace, split).split(split);
        const numberOfBacks = relitivePath.filter(file => file === '..').length;
        return [...absolutePath.slice(0, -(numberOfBacks + 1)), ...relitivePath.filter(file => file !== '..' && file !== '.')].join(split);
    }
};
```

```js
const newPath = path.resolveRelativeFromAbsolute('C:/help/hi/hello/three', '../../two/one'); //returns 'C:/help/hi/two/one'
```