# Get absolute path relative to process.cwd()

Tags: node.js, process, relative-path, absolute-path

I have the following code block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const path = require('path');
const yargs = require('yargs').argv;
const ghpages = require('gh-pages');
const randomstring = require("randomstring");

const dirName = randomstring.generate({
  length: 12,
  charset: 'alphabetic'
});

console.log(__dirname, dirName, process.cwd(), yargs.directory, yargs.branch);

ghpages.publish(path.join(process.cwd(), yargs.directory), {
  branch: yargs.branch,
  clone: `../../../../tmp/${dirName}`
}, () => {
  console.log('removing');
});
```

This requires an absolute path to the `clone` location.

Obviously, I have hard coded it at the moment for testing, but what I want to do is get the absolute path to `/tmp/` from the `process.cwd()`.

So, what I want is if I ran the script in `/home/otis` `../../../../tmp/${dirName}` would become `../../tmp/${dirName}`, so I need to generate the path based on the `process.cwd()`

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS - convert relative path to absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829118/nodejs-convert-relative-path-to-absolute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bad practice to use relative paths, especially to system folders. In case if a project location will be changed, you will have to update your code as well.
If you need the system temp directory, you can use the following:

```
require('os').tmpdir()
```

It will return you correct absolute path to your temporary folder depending on current OS.

Comment: I understand that but the `clone` param expects a relative path, meaning absolute paths will not work.

Comment: Then, as @AvraamMavridis suggested, you can use
`require('path').relative(process.cwd(), require('os').tmpdir())`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `path.resolve` to get the absolute path.

e.g.

```
path.resolve('../src/tmp')
// '/Users/yourusername/src/tmp'
```

Or you can use the [`path.relative( from, to )`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) which gives the relative path between `from` and `to`

So in your case, I guess it is

`path.relative( process.cwd(), "../../../../tmp/" )`

Comment: Could you give an example from `process.cwd()` `/tmp` is the system tmp folder.

Comment: @OtisWright what do you mean `absolute path relative` ? Since you have the absolute url (process.cwd already gives the absolute path) why you need a relative one?

Comment: example added to question of what I mean.