# config.json (TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code in my index.js

```
const config = require('./config.json');
```

and the content of my config.json is

```
{
  "default_prefix": "?"
  }
```

But I am getting an error: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported. What is causing the error?

If I have to show more code, ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./config.json is a relative URL, and it's asking for an absolute URL.

Try converting it to an absolute URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829194/2875073

```js
const configAbsolutePath = require('path').resolve('./config.json')
const config = require(configAbsolutePath);
```

Or you could try another option here for reading a json file: [Using Node.JS, how do I read a JSON file into (server) memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011011/using-node-js-how-do-i-read-a-json-file-into-server-memory)